# What is the difference beetween body and #body

Tags: html, css

In my code I have this:

```
#body {
    background-color: #efeeef;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}
```

And this:

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: solid 10px #000;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

My doubt is because # is an ID selector, but body isnt an ID.

Comment: You've already identified the difference; what problem are you having that's making you ask the question?

Comment: `but body isnt an ID`  Maybe on your page it's not.  It can be if you want.

Comment: Sorry but I didnt think that we could do something like
 <div id="body">...I thought it was something like reserved word...

Comment: @ZeCariocaSilva: You can do that! :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#body` refers to an element with id `body` and `body` refers to `<body ....` of HTML

Example: you could give a `<div id="body">` and the CSS for `#body` would apply to the div.

Answer (score 2):

> My doubt is because # is an ID selector, but body isnt an ID.

Is is now:

```
<div id="body">...</div>
```

IDing elements after element types isn't a great idea (since it can be confusing), but it is legal.

Comment: Example of confusion: `<head id="body">`

Comment: Why would you want to put an ID to a <head> element?

Comment: @holodoc: Because you **CAN**! :-D

Comment: "Because you can" doesn't make it any less useless.

Answer (score 0):

#body refers to any element, not just a body element, that has the id attribute set to "body".

The second one refers to the body tag.

Comment: "Any" should read more like "one and only one". IDs are meant to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

#body is selecting an id named body, so if you had a  it would make changes inside that div, while body would make change